# Response time of web server significantly longer when started from within eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jetty, embedded-jetty, response-time

I am developing an application that includes an embedded Jetty webserver. When I start from within eclipse, I experience response times of about 100ms even for very simple requests which I would expect to return within about 15ms. However, when I package my application to a jar and run it outside eclipse it's as fast as I expect it. I do not run in debug mode and there is no general slowdown when running in eclipse. It rather seems that there is a lower bound for the response time of about 100ms. Does anybody have an explanation for that?

Comment: Measuring performance is not easy, and can be affected by caching. I would try launching your app, sending some messages so everything gets cached / compiled / etc. and then take the measurements. The same with Eclipse.

Comment: Logging?  Swapping?  DNS lookups? What does jvisualvm (in the JDK) say the time is spent on?

Comment: Any output to stdout/stderr can make a big difference due to Eclipse's capturing for the console view.

Answer (score 0):

Are you writing anything to the console? Writing to the Eclipse console can be a lot slower than to a terminal window.